# Nginx rewrites for URL that must have a dash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

This one allows everything with .html extension that contains no slashes:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+).html$ ...
```

I need to add another catch to it: URL must contain at least one dash, then it can be rewritten.

How to do that?

Comment: `rewrite ^/([^/]+-[^/]+)\.html$`. Also you forgot to escape dot(`.`)

Comment: @alexeyten thank you, it works. But How do I add you points for help when you wrote in comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use logic. Word with at least one dash could be expressed as two words with dash between them. So solution is simple:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+-[^/]+)\.html$.
```

Also you forgot to escape dot (`.`)  so your regexp also match url `/somesstrangehtml`